# Postgresql Error - Function return type mismatch

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm looking for some help with a SQL function I am defining under pgAdmin3 for PostGreSQL.

It is a simple function supposed to calculate a ratio given a certain id but when I try to add the function, I get an error message.
Here is the code for the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.func_net_exposure(id_fund_arg text)
RETURNS real AS

$BODY$

DECLARE
    net_exposure real;
    AUM smallint;

BEGIN
    AUM := (SELECT sum(cash_fund_total) from main.main_cash where id_fund = id_fund_arg); 
    net_exposure := (SELECT ROUND(sum(exposure_eur)/(100*AUM)) from main.main_inventory where id_fund = id_fund_arg); 
    return net_exposure;
END;

$BODY$
```

And here is the error message I get when I try to add the function:

> An error has occurred:
>
> 13:13:54: Error: ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to
>   return real DETAIL:  Function's final statement must be SELECT or
>   INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING. CONTEXT:  SQL function
>   "func_net_exposure"

Any clue on how to solve this error?

Comment: Your missing a language specification for the function. It looks like a PL/pgSQL function, yet the system presumably thinks it is an SQL function, as the error message implies. Though I wonder how it even got compiled that way.

Comment: Oh yes, that's exactly what happened, I left the default as 'sql' in the pgadmin definition of the function, instead of 'plpgsql'. Thank your for pointing this out! If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system thinks the function's language is SQL and therefore expects the last statement to be a `SELECT` or `... RETURNING`. The language should be PL/pgSQL. Add a language specification like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.func_net_exposure(id_fund_arg text)
RETURNS real AS

$BODY$

...

$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```